# Is it possible to execute a makefile target without adding it to all?

Tags: makefile

I have a Makefile that includes another bigger makefile

include ../targets.mk

There is an "all:" target in targets.mk that does general stuff for all the Makefiles that include the target.mk. I can edit that file but I really don't want to since that is a common file used by many others and not just me.

I want to create a new folder and copy a file in my Makefile after including targets.mk. Is it possible to do that without editing the targets.mk with "all:" ?

Is it possible to create a new target in my makefile and execute it AFTER all the targets in "all:" have been executed, without adding my target to "all:" ?

Comment: sure, just add `all` as a dependency, eg. `new-target: all`

Comment: @jenesaisquoi that did not seem to work. I created a new target mylib: all in my Makefile it doesn't seem to execute anything under mylib, just all is getting executed as usual

Comment: did you put anything in the body of your rule? `new-target: all\n\t@echo "this is the body"`

Comment: @jenesaisquoi yes it looks like this `mylib: all \n\t @echo "Hello this is Venkat"`

Comment: @jenesaisquoi they are there, they dont get reflected in the code syntax of stackoverflow

Comment: Note also that the default target is whichever appears first in the file.  If you want that not to be 'all' then you'll probably need to put your new rule before the `include` directive.  Wherever you put the new rule, though, you should be able to `make` its target by name: `make mytarget`.

Comment: With the 'mylib: all' change, mylib will only get executed if 'all' completed without an error.Can you share the tail of the output of 'make mylib' ?

Comment: @dash-o & johnbollinger I added a second "all:" target in my Makefile. That got executed after the all target in the targets.mk file. I couldn't do the newtarget thing because all target was being called specifically by the parent makefile. This second all target works exactly the way I wanted it to. Thanks for the help.